# Can I make meatloaf with soy burger meat?

Tags: eggs, meat, hamburgers, soy, meatloaf

I bought beef burgers only to find out they're not actually beef, they're soy burgers. I don't like them, so I want to try and spice them up and give them flavor. Can I defrost the burgers and make meat loaf with the soy meat? I have a good meat loaf recipe, but I am wondering if I can substitute the meat with the soy meat.

Comment: I've removed the complaints about the specific product, because they're not really relevant to your question *and* because the product you named is most certainly beef; either you bought something else or you're mistaken about what you have.

Answer (score 6):

If you hate the soy burgers, you will probably hate meatloaf made from them. Your best bet might be to defrost 1 or 2 burgers and mix them with ground beef (or whatever meat you use for meatloaf) with no more than 25% of the mix being the soy burgers. If you like your first meatloaf, you can always try a little bit higher percentage of the soy burgers next time. Since they're frozen, you have a bit of the luxury of time to use them up.